# info_auto tactic does not print traces anymore in Coq8.5?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I used to use `info_auto` to display the steps actually performed under the hood by an `auto` tactic. However, this no longer seems to work with Coq 8.5 (beta3).

The following example used to work for Coq 8.4:

```
Example auto_example_5: 2 = 2.
Proof.
  info_auto.
Qed.
```

and give me the necessary steps  such as `apply @eq_refl.`.

With Coq8.5, I get a warning:

```
The "info_auto" tactic does not print traces anymore. Use "Info 1 auto", instead.
(* info auto : *)
```

Using `Info 1 auto.` as hinted, I got:

```
<unknown>
```

in the message view. In other occasions, I sometimes get things like

```
<unknown>; refine H
```

But neither is helpful/informational because I can't apply these to finish the proof manually.

What is the proper way to replicate the old `info_auto` function in Coq 8.5?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. Do you use proof general too or do you get it with coqtop?

Comment: Got the same result with coqtop, so i've filed a bug: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4587

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to have been fixed in Coq 8.6.

Comment: And also in Coq 8.5pl3.